# Bitbucket pipeline fails with no useful information for me

Tags: continuous-integration, bitbucket, pipeline

Why is Bitbucket not longer showing any useful error message when a pipeline fails? It could at least show the error that caused it to fail, couldn't it??
This started happening when I began running some steps in parallel, and now I've even reverted that change to get more useful pipeline messages but it's still just like this. Did bitbucket change their policy on displaying output to be completely non helpful?

- yes I know I could try and reproduce all this locally and probably find the error, infact I have done; I could even brute force my way back to successful pipeline builds by regressing each change I made one by one and pushing agai... but that's not the point:

What is going on with Bitbucket that leads to such useless pipeline output? Am I approaching this part of development fundamentally wrong or something? I have a valid bitbucket-pipelines.yml file, so where's my error output?

```
--------------------------------- --------------------------------- --------------------------------- ---------------------------------
Build setup 37s
--------------------------------- --------------------------------- --------------------------------- ---------------------------------

+ umask 000
+ GIT_LFS_SKIP_SMUDGE=1 retry 6 git clone --branch="dev" --depth 50 https://x-token-auth:$REPOSITORY_OAUTH_ACCESS_TOKEN@bitbucket.org/$BITBUCKET_REPO_FULL_NAME.git $BUILD_DIR
Cloning into '/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build'...
+ git reset --hard d7bda3a629010128e42d4222df7c40c62f25b9ca
HEAD is now at d7bda3a testing pipeline reporting
+ git config user.name bitbucket-pipelines
+ git config user.email commits-noreply@bitbucket.org
+ git config push.default current
+ git config http.${BITBUCKET_GIT_HTTP_ORIGIN}.proxy http://localhost:29418/
+ git remote set-url origin http://bitbucket.org/$BITBUCKET_REPO_FULL_NAME
+ git reflog expire --expire=all --all
+ echo ".bitbucket/pipelines/generated" >> .git/info/exclude
+ chmod 777 $BUILD_DIR
Cache "node: node_modules": Downloading
Cache "node: node_modules": Downloaded 122.3 MiB in 7 seconds
Cache "node: node_modules": Extracting
Cache "node: node_modules": Extracted in 9 seconds
Cache "cypress: /root/.cache/Cypress": Downloading
Cache "cypress: /root/.cache/Cypress": Downloaded 160.1 MiB in 6 seconds
Cache "cypress: /root/.cache/Cypress": Extracting
Cache "cypress: /root/.cache/Cypress": Extracted in 6 seconds
Default variables:
    BITBUCKET_BRANCH
    BITBUCKET_BUILD_NUMBER
    BITBUCKET_CLONE_DIR
    BITBUCKET_COMMIT
    BITBUCKET_GIT_HTTP_ORIGIN
    BITBUCKET_GIT_SSH_ORIGIN
    BITBUCKET_PIPELINE_UUID
    BITBUCKET_PROJECT_KEY
    BITBUCKET_PROJECT_UUID
    BITBUCKET_REPO_FULL_NAME
    BITBUCKET_REPO_IS_PRIVATE
    BITBUCKET_REPO_OWNER
    BITBUCKET_REPO_OWNER_UUID
    BITBUCKET_REPO_SLUG
    BITBUCKET_REPO_UUID
    BITBUCKET_SSH_KEY_FILE
    BITBUCKET_STEP_RUN_NUMBER
    BITBUCKET_STEP_TRIGGERER_UUID
    BITBUCKET_STEP_UUID
    BITBUCKET_WORKSPACE
    CI
    DOCKER_HOST
    PIPELINES_JWT_TOKEN
Repository variables:
    AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
    AWS_DEFAULT_REGION
    AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
Images used:
    build : docker.io/cypress/base@sha256:c78baoeubbd117d8abaeu.5d15540b29oeuou38dd8063913e43b4fd4bbf77ecca3eb8a146df
--------------------------------- --------------------------------- --------------------------------- ---------------------------------
npm ci 1m 37s
--------------------------------- --------------------------------- --------------------------------- ---------------------------------

+ npm ci
npm WARN deprecated source-map-url@0.4.1: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated source-map-resolve@0.5.3: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-resolve#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated querystring@0.2.0: The querystring API is considered Legacy. new code should use the URLSearchParams API instead.
npm WARN deprecated babel-eslint@10.1.0: babel-eslint is now @babel/eslint-parser. This package will no longer receive updates.
npm WARN deprecated uglify-es@3.3.9: support for ECMAScript is superseded by `uglify-js` as of v3.13.0
npm WARN deprecated @babel/polyfill@7.12.1:  This package has been deprecated in favor of separate inclusion of a polyfill and regenerator-runtime (when needed). See the @babel/polyfill docs (https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-polyfill) for more information.
npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.12: core-js@<3.23.3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Because of the V8 engine whims, feature detection in old core-js versions could cause a slowdown up to 100x even if nothing is polyfilled. Some versions have web compatibility issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js.
> postinstall
> patch-package
patch-package 6.5.1
Applying patches...
@lightningjs/sdk@5.3.2 ✔
amazon-cognito-identity-js@6.2.0 ✔
buffer@4.9.2 ✔
https-browserify@1.0.0 ✔
isomorphic-unfetch@3.1.0 ✔
node-fetch@2.6.11 ✔
added 2168 packages, and audited 2169 packages in 2m
143 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details
11 low severity vulnerabilities
To address all issues, run:
  npm audit fix
Run `npm audit` for details.

--------------------------------- --------------------------------- --------------------------------- ---------------------------------
Build teardown 1s
--------------------------------- --------------------------------- --------------------------------- ---------------------------------
You already have a 'node' cache so we won't create it again
You already have a 'cypress' cache so we won't create it again
Cache "node: node_modules": Skipping upload for existing cache
Cache "cypress: /root/.cache/Cypress": Skipping upload for existing cache
Searching for test report files in directories named [test-results, failsafe-reports, test-reports, TestResults, surefire-reports] down to a depth of 4
Finished scanning for test reports. Found 0 test report files.
Merged test suites, total number tests is 0, with 0 failures and 0 errors.
```

Answer (score 0):

[![This was hidden!][1]][1]

[![By this 'expand' button][2]][2]

This expand button
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hEn0K.png
Was hiding half the critical UI elements
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IKQzJ.png

Atlassian if you can hide half the crucial UI you should make the fact that it's hidden obvious to the user!
Discovering this button after a week of confusing test output felt like finding an easter egg...

Comment: What exactly helped you in that that menu?